# Uso particular de "se" con el verbo "ser"

Tags: gramática

En un libro "El arte de no amargarse la vida" (España) vi lo siguiente:

*En el caso de Jesús, le enseñé —profundamente— que...y que no **se** es «menos» por no seguir los cánones de la sociedad.*

¿Cómo gramaticalmente se usa "se" en esta oración? Creo que es el caso de pasivo usado con el verbo "ser". Es que es un poco difícil traducirlo a inglés gramaticalmente (*"is not represented as something less than..."*) y por eso tengo dudas.

P.s. Por adelantado agradezco que corrijan errores en mi pregunta en caso de que los haya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd translate it "... one is not something less by virtue of not following society's canons," or perhaps informally/loosely, "... you're not less of a person because you don't follow society's canons."

It feels like the same use of the reflexive as "Eso no se hace!" = "One does not do that!", "You just don't do that!" With action verbs you can render it as a passive voice, "That is simply not done!" but with verbs of being such as *ser* you end up with something completely unintelligible.

Comment: I see. So it is impersonal use of "se", not a passive one. As in "One cannot smoke here. = No se puede fumar aquí."

Comment: I'm not a native speaker but that's how I parsed it, yes.